# why button is still disabled after filling form in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add validation on login and registration form. button disabled till all form validation is completed after that the button should be able to clickable but its not don't know why is I'm doing something wrong?

I have already done same thing in login form and after filling email and password the disabled button enable and I'm able to login using button but don't know why it's not working in registration form.

screenshot

[image: 1]

```
 data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      err_message: "",
      errorMessages: "",
      err_show: false,
      showPass: false,
      validate: false,
      showConPass: false,
      rules: {
        required: (value) => !!value || "Required is requred.",
        min: (v) => v.length >= 6 || "Min 6 characters",
      },
      conPass: [
        (v) => !!v || "Required is requred.",
        (v) => v === this.password || "Passwords do not match",
      ],
      emailRules: [
        (value) => {
          if (value) return true;

          return "E-mail is requred.";
        },
        (value) => {
          if (/.+@.+\..+/.test(value)) return true;

          return "E-mail must be valid.";
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

```
 <v-card class="mx-auto py-10 px-10 mt-10" max-width="500" outlined>
    <ErrorMessage :err_show="err_show" :err_message="err_message" />
    <v-form v-model="validate">
      <v-card-title>Register</v-card-title>

      <v-text-field
        v-model="email"
        :rules="emailRules"
        :error-messages="errorMessages"
        label="Email"
        placeholder="example@gmail.com"
        required
      ></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field
        class="text__Field"
        v-model="password"
        :append-inner-icon="showPass ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
        :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
        :type="showPass ? 'text' : 'password'"
        name="input-10-1"
        label="Password"
        hint="At least 6 characters"
        counter
        @click:append-inner="showPass = !showPass"
      ></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field
        class="text__Field"
        v-model="confirmPassword"
        :append-inner-icon="showPass ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
        :rules="conPass"
        :type="showConPass ? 'text' : 'password'"
        name="input-10-1"
        label="Confirm Password"
        hint="At least 6 characters"
        counter
        @click:append-inner="showConPass = !showConPass"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-form>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn :disabled="!validate" elevation="1" @click="register"
        >Register</v-btn
      >
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
```

Comment: We need to see how you change `validate` value.

Comment: solved.. removed name="input-10-1" from both password and confirm pass field